# coldfusion - remove specific text from string

Tags: coldfusion

I am looking to remove "pharmacy" from an input field before I enter the text into the database.

Example - "Ciaran pharmacy" will show as "Ciaran".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no indication the asker made any attempt to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements are pretty simple:

```
<cfscript>
    name = "Ciaran pharmacy";
    newName = replace(name, 'pharmacy', '');
</cfscript>
```

I suspect there's more complication to it than that.

- Is it only if 'pharmacy' is the last word?
- Is it always just the last word in the name?
- Or is it always 'pharmacy' regardless of where it is in the string?

If it's the 3rd case, specify the 'ALL' parameter:

```
newName = replace(name, 'pharmacy', '', 'ALL');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `REReplace` to remove multiple occurances of the string. And `TRIM` function to remove the spaces before and after.

```
<cfoutput>
    #TRIM(REReplace("pharmacy in Ciaran pharmacy", "pharmacy", "","ALL"))#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: A regex replace is overkill here.  It does the same thing as replace().

Answer (score -1):

```html
local.replaceContent = replace('My Name is developer', 'My', 'I','ALL');
writeDump(local.replaceContent);
abort;
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mjtX.png)